# Angular ui-grid add a row and enter Edit mode

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I would like to have  a button that adds an object to the data array of an ng-grid 3.0. When this row is added I would like to enter edit mode of that row. I tried to do this with

```
gridApi.core.on.rowsRendered
```

However it calls every time the rows are rendered and not just on change. What is the best approach to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the best solution is to JQuery for the row with a timeout

```
$timeout(function() {
      $('.ui-grid-row li').first().dblclick(); 
});
```

Heads up I have a custom template so you will need to adjust your query.